# laravel unique field validation rule on update

Tags: laravel-5

My property listing form contains a **unique reference id** , while adding it works fine, but while editing on save i get an error --- **"The reference has already been taken".**

```html
public $validationRules = [
        'property_type_id' => 'required',
        'property_category_id' => 'required',
        'referance' => 'required|min:5|unique:properties',
    ];
```

How to write the rules for update

http://prntscr.com/vyraod

Answer (score 0):

While update you need not to compare with self so exclude that row like this

```
public $validationRules = [
    'property_type_id' => 'required',
    'property_category_id' => 'required',
    'referance' => 'required|min:5|unique:properties,'.$property->id,
];
```

Comment: 'referance' => 'required|min:5|unique:properties,referance,'.$id


still i am getting - The referance has already been taken.


Table - http://prntscr.com/vyraod


but still i get The referance has already been taken.

Answer (score 0):

While update i set the following validation rules.

Syntax - **'required|min:5|unique:< table name >,< unique field name >,'.$id**

```html
public function rules($id)
    {
        return [
            'property_type_id' => 'required',
            'property_category_id' => 'required',
            'referance' => 'required|min:5|unique:properties,referance,'.$id
        ];
    }


public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules($id));
    }
```